# MS Access Group Specific Values Together

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I am working on a problem in MS Access where I need some aggregated values grouped by certain values.

ExTable1:

```
  Type    TotalHours
+-------+------------+
|  A          10     |
|  A          20     |
|  A          30     |       
|  B          10     |
|  C          10     |
|  D          10     |
|  E          10     |
|  F          10     |
+-------+------------+
```

And I have this query:

```
SELECT Type, SUM(TotalHours)
FROM ExTable1
GROUP BY Type
```

This groups all of the A's, B's, C's, etc.. together, but I also want to group E and F's values together in the same query. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a Union Query:

```
SELECT Type, Sum(TotalHours) As TotalHours
FROM ExTable1
WHERE Type IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
GROUP BY Type;

UNION SELECT 'E & F', Sum(TotalHours)
FROM ExTable1
WHERE Type IN ('E', 'F');
```

Comment: Access 2010 complained *"Circular reference caused by alias 'TotalHours' in query definition's SELECT list."*  Changing the alias to *SumOfTotalHours* allowed it to run without error for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Conditional Aggregate`

```
SELECT Type, 
       SUM(TotalHours),
       SUM(case when Type in ('E','F') then TotalHours else 0 END) as 'E&F total'
FROM ExTable1
GROUP BY Type
```

Comment: Please comment the reason of downvoting so that i can improve my answer

Comment: Unlike SQL Server, MS Access does not support `CASE WHEN` statements.